# How can I access my files through the Internet from a browser?

Tags: server, file-sharing

I remember using a software called [wwwfilesharepro](http://www.wfshome.com) on Windows that allowed me to access any folder through a browser.

Is there a similar way to do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Bruno i am not on an ubuntu server but on ubuntu 11.10. So changing the title to "ubuntu server" doesnot serve my concern.Thanks

Answer (score 9):

## Apache / Lighttpd

Use a web server like `apache` or `lighttpd`, though those are a bit hard to setup if you never did that before.

You can enable directory listings in their configuration, which allows the users to browse and download the files.

## Python's SimpleHTTPServer

As I found on [Simple Http Server support](http://ubuntuguide.net/http-server-support-uploading-files-from-windows-in-ubuntu), Python ships a simple HTTP server - you don't need to install anything.

Just open a terminal, `cd` to the directory you want to share and run

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Then open your browser and access `http://yourip:8000`

## Droppy

Not to serve files, but to receive them via HTTP: http://stackp.online.fr/?p=28

Comment: It most likely uses port 8000 when not specified, but it's nice to be able to switch to any other open port ;)

Comment: I tried on win xp and i got this.. Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ?? while i am connected to the internet..

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means it is listening on all network interfaces, not just a specific one. It should still work. 0.0.0.0 does *not* indicate your IP address.

Comment: ya thanks.. but there is one more problem.. i am not able to access through some other pc over another network. i am able to access through http://127.0.0.1:8000/ though from the pc running simplehttpserver

Comment: See http://www.wfshome.com/faqs.htm#q4