# Where to start with creating a server from which I can retrieve pictures/videos?

Tags: server, media, mediaserver

My end game is that I'd like to have a server with pictures and videos from which I can request to an iOS app.

I currently have a CPU for the server aspect but I don't know where to start. I have never worked with servers before and I'd like to start here. I don't need specific instructions. I'm looking for broad help like which type of linux server should I create, which free tools might be of use, which tutorials have helped you, etc.

I just don't know where to start my research and that's the problem. I'd really like some pointers so that I can then begin my journey.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to access the information from your LAN only or across the internet?  If the latter, your learning curve just bent up quite a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my files through the Internet from a browser?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94281/how-can-i-access-my-files-through-the-internet-from-a-browser)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are looking for:

- file transfer over internet securely
- a nice browser based interface for uploading/checking/modifying files

I would suggest **Owncloud**. ([Official website](https://owncloud.org/))

(Many would think it is overkill but I believe once one tries out such high end tool, other things are trivial and easy.)

For me installing and running Owncloud was not too difficult and I enjoyed learning.

**What it has and how it works:**
It works using database module (open-source) and php (a programming language). Information of files uploaded is stored in the database. Access is provided via web-interface available on browser or mobile applications. Installing it requires installation of webserver, php and mysql database followed by Owncloud itself.

- Files can be uploaded by browser.
- Apps available for android, iOS, blackberry, and of course linux and Windows.
  Link for video introduction [Owncloud 9- youtube](https://youtu.be/g3b0XDpcvuc).

---

If you are not running another server applications then setting a server dedicated for owncloud is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I prefer using 16.04 LTS with apache (webserver), MySQL(database), php 7, SSL for secure transer and  some modification for optimized transfers, + auto-backups. (If you think this tool is good for you and you need installation help, feel free to ask.)